# Does Euler include Maxima?

Tags: windows

Referring to the two math softwares, I want to know if [Euler](http://eumat.sourceforge.net/) includes [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) inside it. So, if I download and install the Windows version of Euler, will I be installing Maxima as well?

So, which one is "better"?

Comment: What "two math softwares"?

Comment: Look here http://math-blog.com/2007/06/02/3-awesome-free-math-programs/

Comment: @Billy By "two math softwares", I mean Euler and Maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://eumat.sourceforge.net/download.html:

> This is a self extracting Windows installer for Euler, including Maxima, (…)

Maxima is one component of Euler, mainly handling symbolic computations.

Comment: <s>So... this means I should get Euler?</s> Nevermind, I'm just going to download it.